# Video Stabilization with spin product OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ffmpeg

I'm trying to stabilize video using OpenCV, but my video is a walkaround 360 spin like this [spin](http://cdn.spincar.com/spincar-static/20190909/?_=0c17f5826cd53c#!customer=antelopevalleyford!vin=3fa6p0hdxlr230801!canonicalhostname=avford.com!stscolor=00A19B%2CF5A623%2C00A19B!lang=en!popoutenabled!region=us!use_container_height), but the stabilize not perfect has a shaking because the optical flow not working perfectly with the spined video

can you find python code [here](https://gist.github.com/ahmedAlmasri/5b0e98f1462e29e73c1799848c27159f)

and I'm trying to use `FFmpeg` but still, have the same issue,

this command

```
INPUT=$1
STB_OUTPUT=stb1.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i "$INPUT" -vf vidstabdetect=stepsize=32:shakiness=5:accuracy=15:result="$TRF" -f null -

ffmpeg -y -i "$INPUT" -vf vidstabtransform=input="$TRF":smoothing=30,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4  "$STB_OUTPUT"
```